# Is it possible to transfer an in-game item to another player without cloning?

Tags: protocols, uniqueidentifier, data-transfer

Imagine I want to transfer an in-game item to another player (e.g. 1000 credits / a "Pokemon" / a character):

- Channel can be through LAN, Bluetooth, paper codes, FTL or any other.
- No intervention of third party or server, that is player to player directly.

Would it be possible to carry out this making sure the first player "loses" the item while the receiving player "creates" the item (meaning no cloning or losing forever the item)?
What would be a general explanation of the protocol?

Non-perfect example to illustrate:

1. 1st device creates a code with the item.
2. 2nd device inputs that code (to "receive" the item) and generates a confirmation code.
3. 1st device inputs that code to "lose" the item.
4. Etc.